# How to link an .a library with an .asm file?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm, static-libraries, ld

As the question mentions i am trying to link an .a library with an .asm file. I am using Ubuntu, nasm and gcc for doing so with the following MRE and commands:

```
nasm -f elf64 -o use.o use.asm
nasm -f elf64 -o strlen.o strlen.asm

ar rc libstring.a strlen.o
ranlib libstring.a

ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none -L. -lstring -o use.bin use.o
```

The used files look like this:
strlen.asm:

```
BITS 64
GLOBAL strlen

;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
; @func strlen
;
; @params String str
;
; @returns uint_32 length
;-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

strlen:
push rcx
push rsi

xor eax, eax
xor ecx, ecx
mov rsi, [rsp + 0x10]

jmp .foreach

.inc_i:
inc ecx

.foreach:
lodsb
or al, al
jnz .inc_i

.return:
mov eax, ecx
pop rsi
pop rcx
ret
```

use.asm:

```
BITS 64

GLOBAL _start
EXTERN strlen

_start:
push str
call strlen
cli
hlt

str: DB "String!", 0x00
```

I do NOT expect them to do something, they should just compile. Currently the linker gives this error:

```
ld: use.o: in function `_start':
use.asm:(.text+0x6): undefined reference to `strlen'
```

Since the error does not mention that the file could not be found, i guess the naming convention of .a files is correct. But why does it not find the method then?

Comment: You need to place library operands after object files that need them.  It's the same with any language.

Comment: Also, your function has label `_strlen` but you call it by the name `strlen`.  That's a different name.  You need to use the same name in both definition and call.

Comment: Thats a whoopsie in the in the code, i already fixed it in the files. Lets try to move around the flags now ^^

Comment: Works now. Bruh.

Comment: Cool!  Write up what you did to solve your problem as an answer so others with the same problem can benefit from this!

Comment: When was the timer removed? Last time i wrote a question i answered myself, i had to wait for 24 hours after posting to pass.

Comment: Hold up, the timer was for accepting the own question, not for writing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to solve this, one has to order the -L and -l flags in a way, they are placed after the files which require them. When using multiple libraries in different locations, one has to make sure the repositioning doesn't misposition the -L flag(s), that could cause some trouble aswell.

So in this MRE, the ld command should look like this: 
`ld -static -nostdlib -build-id=none use.o -L . -l string -o use.bin`

Also don't forget to `sudo chmod +x make.sh` when using a bash script to compile, that might give you 5 minutes of head scratching ^^

Comment: Note that the location of the `-L` flag doesn't matter (though it's conventional to place it before any operands).  Only `-l` operands have to be ordered.  And `sudo`  is never never never needed to compile software.  Do not use `sudo`.  You are just causing more complex issues to solve.